# He is visited vs He is visiting

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I personally think these two sentences have the same meaning.

> 1. He is visited.
> 2. He is visiting.

In the same way:

> The CLI is a globally installed npm package and provides the vue command in your terminal.

In this context, why they say installed instead of Install or Installing?

I'm having a problem to understand the concept of using ED- adjective and ING - adjective. If you say "He is visited" is not correct grammar, then why "I'm bored" or "He is disappointed" are correct?

Can someone tell me the differences between these two and are these grammatically correct?

Comment: The title of your question, and the first part of its body, describe something different from the second part of the body of your question. *He is visited* means that somebody visits him. *He is visiting* means that ***he*** is the one performing the action. The context, and therefore meaning, of the verb forms in the second part of your question is different. So—which are you asking about? Visiting or installing?

Answer (score 1):

> "The CLI is a globally installed npm package and provides the vue command in your terminal." In this context, why they say installed instead of Install or Installing?

In that sentence, "installed" is a past participle which is being used as an adjective. That is, "the CLI is an NPM package which [has been|is designed to be] globally installed"; the stated context isn't enough to determine which of "has been" or "is designed to be" is intended.

To consider your two suggestions:

- "The CLI is a globally installing npm package." - this is wrong in that context. The sentence means "The CLI is an NPM package which is, right now, in the process of installing globally."
- "The CLI is a globally install npm package." - this is always wrong; there is no part of speech which "install" could be serving here that would make the sentence grammatical.